# Enterprise Architect doesn't import C++ classes with DLL-export macro

Tags: reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

In my project intended to be built as DLL each class declaration has a macro between `class` ans class-name e.g:

```
class DLL_EXPORT FSTools
```

These classes are not importen with reverse-engineering feature.

Is there a way to do it without modifying the source-code?

Version of EA is 7.5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the macro as a language macro in Enterprise Architect. For version 9.0 and up its in Settings -> preprocessor macros. In the window that opens, select your language (C++ I presume), click "Add New" and enter your macro as it is defined in your code. You must do this for every export macros your have.

See :

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.0/software_engineering/languagemacros.html